# Action Cable in Rails 5.2 throwing a NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, actioncable

I'm setting up Action cable in my Rails 5.2 app for comments on a listings page. jQuery is not my strong point but I'm sure I've got that end right. I'm receiving this error when I load the page. I'm have disabled Turbolinks so the call on the jQuery coffee script I'm sure is correct. I've double checked file locations and typos and cannot for the life of me figure out why the method 'channel' is not being called. Here are the files.

app/assets/javascripts/channels/listings.coffee

```coffee
jQuery ->
comments = $('#comments')
if comments.length > 0 
    App.global_chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
        channel: "ListingsChannel"
        listing_id: comments.data("listing-id")
    },
    connected: ->
    disconnected: ->
    received: (data) ->
        comments.append data['comment']
    send_comment: (comment, listing_id) ->
        @perform 'send_comment', comment: comment, listing_id: listing_id
$('#new_comment').submit (e) ->
    $this = $(this)
    textarea = $this.find('#comment_content')
    if $.trim(textarea.val()).length > 1
        App.global_chat.send_comment textarea.val(),
        comments.data('listing-id')
        textarea.val('')
    e.preventDefault()
    return false
```

app/channels/listings_channel.rb

```rb
class ListingsChannel < ApplicationCable::channel
    def subscribed
        # point to the stream
        stream_from "listings_#{params['listing_id']}_channel"
    end

    def unsubscribed
    end

    # uses the method in the coffee script to get the data required to attach to the comment
    def send_comment(data)
        current_user.comments.create!(content: data['comment'], listing_id: data['listing_id'])
    end
end
```

Error message:

```
[ActionCable] [bradley@email.com] [2] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vZ2xvYmFsLWFieC9Vc2VyLzI)
[ActionCable] [bradley@email.com] [2] Could not execute command from ({"command"=>"subscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"ListingsChannel\",\"listing_id\":6}"}) [NoMethodError - undefined method `channel' for ApplicationCable:Module]: /Users/bradley/Development/app_name/app/channels/listings_channel.rb:1:in
```

app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```rb
module ApplicationCable
      class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
            identified_by :current_user

            def connect
                self.current_user = find_verified_user
                logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
                logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.id
            end

            protected

            def find_verified_user
                # recreating devise functionality for current_user methods
                if verified_user = env['warden'].user
                    verified_user
                end
            end
      end
 end
```

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    # grabs current user and builds the comment based on relationships set up
    @comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_params)
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
```

end

app/jobs/comment_broadcast_job.rb

```rb
class CommentBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
#create queue/list served in order
queue_as :default

def perform(comment)
    # start broadcast on actioncable / create a channell/ render comment
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "listings_#{comment.listing.id}_channel", comment: render_comment(comment)
end

private

def render_comment(comment)
    # call the comments controller and render the partial in the views, pass in the variable to render
    CommentsController.render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment }
end
```

end

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require snackbar
//= require activestorage
//= require cable
//= require_tree .
```

The form inspected to see if there is any mislaid # call or anything. 
[image]

Not sure what else I can add here. Hard to find anything related to that error but its clear it's not finding something along the way.

any help would be more that appreciated. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** I have yet to use ActionCable myself so take my response with a grain of salt.

In your `app/channels/listings_channel.rb` file `ApplicationCable::channel` should have a capital "C" on channel.

**Current:** `class ListingsChannel < ApplicationCable::channel`

**Required:** `class ListingsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel`

It looks like Ruby things that there is a function called `channel` in your `ApplicationCable` module and that's why you're getting an error.

Also, since you didn't post the code, make sure that you have a `Channel` class within the `ApplicationCable` namespace. Based off [this repository](https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples/blob/master/app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb), you should also have this file in your app folder:

```rb
# /channels/application_cable/channel.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh!!! Nice one. I must have went over those files 100 times and just didn't see that. "my eyes!!!!". Thanks a million @rparr. Fair play.

Comment: Thanks for the taken the time to read the question rparr. There was a lot going on in it. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, @Bradley, I'm glad I could help. Sometimes all it takes is someone else to take a look at your code. :)